# Keep text with previous line - LaTeX equation and next sentence

Tags: formatting, equations

What I am trying to do is probably very similar to the "Keep with next/previous" in MS Word. I have an equation and its description in two consecutive lines. I would like the two lines to shift to the next page if they cannot be in the same page.

```
\begin{equation}
   Incoming\ Radiation, F_\lambda = S_\lambda.\cos \phi
   \label{eq:SolSpecIrrad}
\end{equation}
Where $\phi$ is the solar zenith angle. % This line is getting pushed 
% to the next page, as the equation is the last 
% thing on the previous page.
```

Comment: Look into the `needspace` package.  Something like `\needspace{1in}
\begin{equation}
   Incoming\ Radiation, F_\lambda = S_\lambda.\cos \phi
   \label{eq:SolSpecIrrad}
\end{equation}
Where $\phi$ is the solar zenith angle.` should work.

Comment: don't use math italic for words! `Incoming\ Radiation` should be `\textit{Incoming Radiation}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was sure that text in math should not be in italics?

Comment: @runartrollet `\textrm` is anther possibility of course, although I assumed the OP wanted italics here.

Answer (score 4):

You could put it into a `minipage`, or use the `samepage`-package. I've added here the `mathtools`-package, which I would advice you to use. As commented by David Carlisle, you shouldn't spell out complete words in math-environments, as each individual letter will be typeset as a variable. You could put them in `\text{Word}`.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{17.5cm}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{equation}
   \text{Incoming Radiation}, F_\lambda = S_\lambda.\cos \phi
   \label{eq:SolSpecIrrad}
\end{equation}
Where $\phi$ is the solar zenith angle.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: a single `\text{...}` would be better: `\text{Incoming Radiation, }`.

Answer (score 2):

Set `\postdisplaypenalty` to 10000 for the special case:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\commentedequationtext}{} % initialize
\newenvironment{commentedequation}[1]
 {\renewcommand\commentedequationtext{#1}%
  \postdisplaypenalty=10000
  \equation}
 {\endequation\commentedequationtext}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{6\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{commentedequation}{where $\phi$ is the solar zenith angle.}
   \label{eq:SolSpecIrrad}
   \text{Incoming Radiation:}\quad F_\lambda = S_\lambda\cdot\cos \phi
\end{commentedequation}

\end{document}
```

You'll see that if `5\baselineskip` is used, the equation will be on page 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to do what you need with nested `tcolorbox`. I've painted in red just to demonstrate a very long equation, the white background area inside is the description box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}   
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=red,colback=red!10,breakable,
]
\begin{equation}
   Incoming\ Radiation, F_\lambda = S_\lambda.\cos \phi
   \label{eq:SolSpecIrrad}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2-4]

Equation stuff, equation stuff,  equation stuff, equation stuff, equation stuff, equation stuff, equation stuff,  

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=0mm,left=0mm,width=\linewidth,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt]

Where $\phi$ is the solar zenith angle. % This line is getting pushed 
% to the next page, as the equation is the last 
% thing on the previous page. 

Description, description, description, description, %description, description, description
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}    
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```